# How would I create an array list while separating the values?

Tags: java, string

So basically what Im trying to do is make a vocab practice game in java. I have java reading the .txt file and reporting them to the console. The data is separated by the "|" character because I use commas in my .txt file.

Here Is The Code.

```
package sat.vocab.practice;

import java.io.FileReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SATVocabPractice {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Jordan/Documents/GitHub/SAT-Vocab-Practice--New-/src/sat/vocab/practice/Words.txt"), '|' , '"' , 0);

        String[] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            if (nextLine != null) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextLine));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The words are formatted as follows.

```
Word | Type of Speach: Definition

labyrinth|n: 1. an intricate combination of paths or passages in which it is difficult to find one's way or to reach the exit. 2. any confusingly intricate state of things or events; a bewildering complex.
cower|v: 1. to crouch, as in fear or shame.
```

The Data That We Get Back From The Code Is Formatted As 
[ cower|v: 1. to crouch, as in fear or shame.]

I need the data to go into two array lists one for words (before the |) and one for definitions (after the |).

Comment: i like to use explode for this in php

Comment: @JoshuaByer It's not clear how that's helpful.

Comment: Please take care to format your code properly so it's easy to read and think about.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String[] array = nextLine.split("\\|");
```

this function will split you `String` by character `|`. Assign this to new variable and use later to add each element to separate list.

`array[0]` this is the word

`array[1]` and this is the definition.

Comment: Where would I add this into my code to add them to the array lists? Thank you

Comment: Inside the for-loop :)